# number of topics in LDA model (coherence)

Tags: topic-model, lda, rstudio, coherence

[image]I want to fit a LDA model using RStudio, but there are some trouble in the determination of topics number.
Perplexity and coherence are suggested to do this work, so first I use LDA and perplexity command to get the perplexity vs number of topics. However, I don't find a function or package to get the coherence in RStudio. topic_coherence command in package "topicdoc" can return coherence of each topic, makes me confused, it is an array not a coherence score.

Comment: Please use markdown code blocks (with [syntax highlighting](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting)) to share your code instead of screenshots.